# Restrict API key access to only one API in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, api-key, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have deployed a Google Cloud Endpoints v2 API with the `apiKeyRequired = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE` to restrict access to clients who have a api key. I have created an api key in the Credentials page in Cloud platform and I am able to access the api with the key.[image]

I now want to give this API key to a third party consumer, but since I have deployed multiple API's with Google Cloud Endpoints I want to give them access to only one of them.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [article](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/control-api-callers). Basically, the customer should use their own API key, and you should grant access to the API via Cloud Console.

Comment: This renders Google Cloud Endpoints useless for us, if every customer has to create a Google Cloud project just to use our API. Is there an other, easier, way for us to give access to the API?